# How To Make a Javascript Variable Only Accessible From One Script Tag?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I was wondering if it was possible to make a variable only accessible from the script tag that it is defined in in an HTML webpage. For example, if I declare a variable in a script tag, the other script tags in the page can't access it. Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      //This is script 1
      var abc = "this is a variable" // How can I make this variable only accessible by this script?
    </script>
    <script>
      alert(abc) // This should give 'abc is not defined' error because it is only accessible in the other script tag.
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to make this work, so that the other script tags can not access the variables of the first one?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual problem you're trying to solve here? Are you concerned about scripts included in the page reading the contents of variables you've declared in a separate `<script>` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use either `const` or `let` to assign variables.
2. Wrap the variable in a block, i.e. `{}`.

```html
<script>
  {
    const abc = "this is a variable";
  }
</script>

<script>
  alert(abc);
</script>
```